# Jekyll page specific CSS

Tags: css, jekyll

I'm building a website using Jekyll for the first time, and so far it's truly amazing.

My problem is: I want to be able to add specific CSS to specific pages of the website.

The question is: is there a clever way to add some lines of code to a specific page, maybe using YAML front matter?

Before using Jekyll, I used to link a separate .css file in the `<head>`, like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">       # main stylesheet
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/page/style.css">  # secondary stylesheet
```

**Update #1**

I found this document https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#using-variables-names-for-the-include-file.
It seems to accomplish something similar to what I'm looking for.
The only issue is that (due to the way I set up my template) the CSS ends up being included in the `<body>` tag. Everything seems to work fine tho.

## Solution

I solved the problem by including the following lines in the `<head>`:

```
<style>
{% if page.style %} {% include css/{{ page.style }}.css %} {% endif %}
</style>
```

That way I'm able to include a whole stylesheet from `_includes`.

So far it works without issues and I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The clever answer is in your question : use a front matter variable to define which style is applied for a specific page.

```
---
title:  any page
style:  one         # defines body main class
layout: default
---
```

**layouts/default.html**

```
<body class="{% if page.style %}{{ page.style }} {% endif %}">
...
```

**your css**

```
one: { background: #f00; }
two: { background: #0f0; }
...
```

Comment: Hello David, I would actually like to include a whole stylesheet.

I read more carefully the Jekyll docs, and I found this: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#using-variables-names-for-the-include-file

I'm trying it right now:
1. I create a style_index.html with some <style> in it, and I put it in the _includes folder
2. I add "style: style_index.html" to the Front Matter of the page
3. I add "{% include {{ page.style }} %}" in the current page (which ends up in the body, so not the most correct place I guess...)
And it seems to work, but I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply (yeah, I'm that bad at following up lol).

I solved by using `{% if page.style %} {% include css/{{ page.style }}.css %} {% endif %}` so that I'm able to include a whole stylesheet in the head.So far it works without issues, I'm very happy with it.